# How to deal with a matrix too big to be stored in memory?

Tags: c++, exception, memory, try-catch

I have a problem with my c++ program; I need to read a matrix from a .csv file, and I want to be able to handle the case in which the matrix is too big to be stored in memory.  I thought about using a try/catch clause, but I can't get it to work;

```
try {
        stringstream convertor(line);
            columns=0;
            while (getline(convertor, token,',')) 
             {

                         tmp.push_back(stoi(token));//first vector made by   int read from csv file


                         if (token=="0"){ 
                            zero.push_back(make_triplet(rows,columns,0));
                            contzero++;

                            }

                columns++; 

                }


        matrix.push_back((tmp));
        }
        catch (std::exception& ba)
                         {
                        cerr << "bad_alloc caught: " << ba.what() << '\n';
                         }
```

The problem is that if I give it as input as matrix 1 million x 1 million (which should be too big for my 4 Gb ram), it won't enter the catch clause.

What is the correct way to handle this problem?

Comment: You may have encountered the phenomenon of memory overcommitment. Google it. You cannot do much about it from within C++. You may disable overcommitment in your OS altogether, or you may provide a safe memory limit for your program. What is your OS?

Comment: are you looking for a way to fit the matrix into memory and process it (when it actually is too big to fit into memory) or do you just want to know how to throw an exception when you run out of memory?

Comment: @tobi303 The second one. If the memory is too big I just want to print "too big" and close the program

Comment: How do you feed that program an array of 10^12 elements?

Answer (score 0):

How about using "Sparse Matrix"? A sparse matrix is effective if most of the elements of the matrix area zero.

There is [Sparse Matricies library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix_sparse.htm) on Boost. It might fit the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to process data that doesn't fit the memory, then you'll need to store the container on disk and only cache part of it in memory at any given time.

If all you want to do is to refuse accepting too big input, then the problem with your current approach is that there is no guarantee that `std::bad_alloc` is ever thrown and indeed, operating systems that [overcommit](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/overcommit-accounting) memory, won't do that for you.

What you can and what programs typically do, is use an arbitrary limit on the memory. If `sizeof(element) * dimension1 * dimension2` is bigger than the limit, then inform the user. Make the limit configurable, so that users can set it according to their available memory. Use a default value for the limit according to minimum memory requirement that you want to support.